# Postgres - how select jsonb key value pairs as colums?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgres-10

having records in `test` table like so (`metrics` column is jsonb type):

```
id     name      metrics
1      machine1  {"metric1": 50, "metric2": 100}
2      machine2  {"metric1": 31, "metric2": 46}
```

I would like to select the metrics as additional columns, e.g. (pseudo-code):

```
Select *, json_each(test.metrics) from test;
```

to get the result like:

```
id  name       metric1   metric2 
1   machine1   50        100
2   machine2   31        46
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `->>` operator:

```
select id, name, 
       metrics ->> 'metric1' as metric1,
       metrics ->> 'metric2' as metric2
from test;
```

Comment: Okay, that's nice, thank you. But I have like 50 metrics and would like to map them dynamically in Java client. So I would prefer to select them via wildcard or something. Is that possible?

Comment: @milkamar: no, that's not possible. But why not simply send the JSON to the Java application and process it there?

Comment: Yeah, didn't strike me. ObjectMapper should do the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `->>`

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=49101abb0861bd708e3e04be6b811dec)

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    metrics ->> 'metric1' as metric1,
    metrics ->> 'metric2' as metric2
FROM t
```

Note, that now the `metric` columns are of type `text`. If you want to them to be of type `integer`, you need to cast them additionally:

```
(metrics ->> 'metric1')::int
```

Comment: Okay, that's nice, thank you. But I have like 50 metrics and would like to map them dynamically in Java client. So I would prefer to select them via wildcard or something. Is that possible?

Comment: That's not simply possible. The output columns must be pre-defined. So you need to process your JSON in the backend if you need this.